# fxcop execution failed with return code 515

Tags: .net, sonarqube, fxcop, sonar-runner

I have installed sonar and sonar runner in my machine trying to analyze a dotnet mvc project in the sonar-runner.properties the content is :

```
# Required metadata
sonar.projectKey=Test:TwitterWithAOP1
sonar.projectVersion=trunk
sonar.projectName=TwitterWithAOP
# Paths to source directories.
# Paths are relative to the sonar-project.properties file. Replace "\" by "/" on Windows.
# Do not put the "sonar-project.properties" file in the same directory with the source code.# (i.e. never set the "sonar.sources" property to ".")
sonar.sources=C:/Users/barumugham/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/TwitterWithAOP/TwitterWithAOP
sonar.language=cs
# Encoding of the source 
codesonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8 
# Additional parameters
sonar.my.property=value
sonar.fxcop.installDirectory=C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft FxCop 1.36
sonar.fxcop.assemblyDependencyDirectories=C:/Users/barumugham/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/TwitterWithAOP/TwitterWithAOP/bin/
```

My execution is showing fxcop execution failed with return code 515. Check fxcop documentation for more details

Comment: So you've check FxCop documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is

```
sonar.fxcop.assemblyDependencyDirectories=/gac  The misssing assemblies path was set to the gac in the sonar-project.properties file and also this line

sonar.dotnet.visualstudio.solution.file=name.sln indicating the solution path.
```

Now the sonar-runner works.